# duplicate finding prior to adding on sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Morning all

can somebody advise me where i am i going wrong? i have a userform whereby it adds data to worksheet however i want message box to show if the first name in column B and surname in column C already exist prior to adding on sheet.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("B:C"), Me.textbox1.Value and Me.textbox2.Value) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "This staff member already exists"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: I think you are trying `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Columns(2), Me.textbox1.Value) > 0 And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Columns(3), Me.textbox2.Value) > 0 Then` But do not use this. Use [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) and not `CountIf` because both condition can be true if values are in different rows.

Comment: Hi Siddharth sorry how do I write the code then sorry

Comment: I can give you the code. It is pretty easy but I would like you to try it first. I already gave you the link above.

Comment: i have tried this and get an error  If WorksheetFunction.Find(Sheet21.Columns(2), Me.TextBox1.Value) > 0 And WorksheetFunction.FindNext(Sheet21.Columns(3), Me.TextBox2.Value) > 0 Then
         MsgBox "Applicant already exist"
         Exit Sub
            End If

Comment: Please read my first comment on why you should not use `CountIf` and what you should be using. It took me just 4 minutes to write the code. Ok here is the deal. I will post the answer with the code that I have written if you show me your attempt to use ` .Find and .FindNext` from the above link to solve the issue.

Comment: **Why not to use CountIf** Here is an example. `TextBox1` contains `Harin` and `TextBox2` contains `Potter` and cell `B1` has `Harin` and `C2` has `Potter` then `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Columns(2), Me.textbox1.Value)` and `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Columns(3), Me.textbox2.Value)` both will give you `1` but this is not what you want because both of them are in different rows.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `CountIfs()` rather than `CountIf` but that will not be compatible with say Excel 2003/2011. Here is an example `If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheet2.Columns(2), Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheet2.Columns(3), Me.TextBox2.Value) > 0 Then`

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout i have tried all sort of things and not getting anywhere :| it probably will take me forever to write this as i am not good at writing codes

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout sorry first name and surname will always be in a same row

Comment: See the `CountIfs()` comment above. Off to gym. Will look at this in 2 hours when i am back.

Comment: Yh no problem it has sort of worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Find` and `FindNext`

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CheckExists()

    Dim rng As Range, firstFind As String, bExists As Boolean
    Dim firstname As String, surname As String
    firstname = Me.textbox1.Value
    surname = Me.textbox2.Value

    ' find in column B
    Set rng = Sheet1.Columns(2).Find(firstname, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ' not found
    Else
        firstFind = rng.Address
        Do
            If rng.Offset(0, 1) = surname Then ' Column C
                bExists = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set rng = Sheet1.Columns(2).FindNext(rng)
            
         Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> firstFind
    End If

    If bExists Then
         MsgBox firstname & " " & surname & " already exists", vbExclamation, "Row " & rng.Row
         Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```